# Synchronous call to Java WSDL service not available in Silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, wsdl

Someone else created a WSDL service for me in Java. There is so far only one simple method to call. We tested this method in a C# console app by adding a service reference with the service's url. If I make a call to the generated method that has 'Async' at the end, I get an error. However, since the synchronous method is available, making calls to that work perfectly.

The trouble is, when I add a service reference to the same service from within a Silverlight project, the synchronous method is not available. A call to the async method also errors out.

Is there a different way I can do this so I can call the synchronous method from Silverlight?

Comment: SilverLight can never do synchronous access to anything, not even services. What's wrong with calling the async version? Which error do you get when you try?

Comment: An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://[server name]:8080/oracleProjectWS/services/ProjectDetails'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.

Comment: The problem is, I can access it in a cross-domain way from a console app on my local machine or from an ASP.Net web project, also hosted on a different domain, without needing a cross-domain policy.

Comment: That seems to have nothing to do with async.

Comment: In a console app or asp.net app, there is a method called 'getProjectDetailInfo' that is available through the service reference. 'getProjectDetailInfoAsync' is also available. 'getProjectDetailInfo' is a synchronous method and works just as expected.

In the Silverlight project, only 'getProjectDetailInfoAsync' is available, but it causes an error.

Comment: The error probably has nothing to do with the fact that it's being called async. Also, it's not that the method is synchronous or not - it's whether the Service Reference has generated a synchronous way to call the method. In Silverlight, there will be no synchronous way to call it.

Comment: Just for sanity sake, have you added a client access policy file to the host ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I sent it to the other person who made the service and he's looking into how to configure it for our needs. Thank you Mashton for the link and thanks John Saunders for letting me know what it's not.